# How to get an array of objects of a little more complex SQL with Zend2 and Doctrine2?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to map a working result from Zend2 / Doctrine2 to loop through the results in my index.phtml.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT
    m.id, 
    t.name, 
    m.track_id, 
    m.date, 
    min(r.date) as minpost, 
    max(r.date) as maxpost, 
    count(r.id) as races
FROM 
    Meeting m, Track t, Race r
WHERE
    m.track_id = t.id and r.meeting_id = m.id and m.date >= CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY
    m.id, t.name, m.track_id, m.date
```

The Query works and I get back a result like this (displayed with var_dump):

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => int 1
      ...
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => int 2
      ...
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => int 3
      ...
```

I could not get it to match a result I got in a basic Zend2 / Doctrine2 - example, which looked like:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(Album\Entity\Album)[305]
    ...
  ...
```

**So my question is:
How can I get an array of objects from my displayed SQL with Zend2 / Doctrine2, so that I can loop through itin my index.phtml?**

I am thankfull for any answer!

Best regards
rholtermann

Comment: Im not quite sure if I understood your question 100%, but wouldn't this be trivial if you used DQL?

Comment: I don't know if it is trivial, but I will try it. If you can give me an example I would be very thankfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your question you want a result that is an array of objects instead a result that is a nested array with object properties.
If you want an array of objects you should change your SELECT clause. Now you ask for different properties in your SELECT clause meaning Doctrine will never return a homogeneous collection of objects of a certain type. Just change the select clause to for example:

`SELECT m FROM Meeting m WHERE ...`

If you want to fetch join the `Track` and `Race` entities in your result you should use fetch join as described [here in the doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)

Doctrine will then return the joined entities hydrated in the result (in the Meeting collection).

Comment: Thanks Wilt, your answer made me rethink my strategy, I read the documentation a little too quick. A homogeneous collection was exactely what I wanted to have, but it is impossible. So I loop through an array of arrays right now and it works like a charme. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I re-read your question and I think I gotcha now. Instead of the Object you probably want the array values to be displayed.

The result of your query is a `array` full of Doctrine Entity Objects. Which means you can just:

```
foreach($yourObjects as $key => $entity) {
   //getter and setter methods like 
   ...
   var_dump($entity->getId());
   ...
}
```

Additionally you could implement a method that returns the Entity's variables rather then calling every getter.

```
//within your Entity.php
public function getArrayCopy()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer cptnk, now I do exactely what you said I loop through an array of arrays. I would have marked your answer as the correct one, but it was Wilt who was leading me into the correct way. But a big thanks for your answer.